# Best Approach and Classifier for Binary Classification Problem

Tags: classification, training, binary

I am trying to build a binary classifier, and I am wondering what is the best approach for data segmentation, training/testing, performance evaluation, selecting classifier type, and overall approach to this?

Data type: Data from 100 subjects. For each subject, multiple instances (Ni for the i-th subject) of measurements were 30 seconds segment of 3 channel ECG were taken, and 5 features were extracted for each channel and each 30 seconds segment of ECG. Hence the dataset is 100 x Ni x 3 x 5, where Ni is the number of measurement taken for the i-th subject (i=1 to 100). The outcome for the subject is binary, and hence say 0 and 1.

In this case, since there are multiple and variable numbers of measurements, how should that fact should be adjusted for training and testing?